# Change filter approach in powershell tab auto complete

Tags: powershell

Currently in Powershell when I use tab to check the possible options for completion  it show just items that has the param text in the beginning of the word.

Example: Given the items

- Program Files
- Local Programs
- Another item

When

```
cd Pro [tab]
```

Returns:

- Program Files

So, it will show as option all the directories where the name starts with *Pro*. But I want to change this behavior, instead of the premise "Starting with" I would like a "Contains".

In this case my outcome would be:

Example: Given the items

- Program Files
- Local Programs
- Another item

When

```
cd Pro [tab]
```

Returns:

- Program Files
- Local Programs

Comment: powershell is opensource, go for it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is another way, I would say so, but I solved it with [TabExpansion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/26/the-new-tabexpansion-feature/):

```
function TabExpansion($line, $lastWord) {
    if ($line.StartsWith("cd ")) {
        return Get-ChildItem -Name *$lastWord*
    }
}
```